# Query to return input date and return three weeks ago

Tags: function, date, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a create query (stored procedure or function) that will take an input date and return a date that is a Sunday 3 weeks ago for example. or any day of the week a certain number of weeks past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the DATEADD() function here, you can add/subtract a time period from a date:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Should be what you need.